# How to set or recover files header from response body in Go?

Tags: file, go, http

I'm having some problems with the recovery of a number of files header that were sent through a response from a GET request in order to be compressed. The main issue here is I want to get rid of the default date Go is setting for the files "November 30th, 1979" (once the files are zipped), and instead of that, I want the current date to appear. However I don't know how to modify or even retrieve the header from the files, because I'm receiving an io.ReadCloser type from the response body.

Here is the current code

```
archive := zip.NewWriter(w)
            attachment := "attachment; filename=someZipFile.zip")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", attachment)

            for i := 0; i < len(bodies); i++ { // bodies are response bodies, corresponding to "downloaded" files
                defer bodies[i].Close()
                fmt.Println(filenames[i])

                w, err := archive.Create("someZipFile/" + filenames[i])
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("File couldn't be created")
                    return true
                }

                if _, err := io.Copy(w, bodies[i]); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("File couldn't be written")
                    return true
                }

            }
            archive.Close()
```

I want to clarify what could I do, whether to create a new header or edit the existing one, and if the former, how to get the files header. And in the worst case, figuring out a completely new solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create is a helper method that calls CreateHeader.  Call CreateHeader directly to specify file metadata:

```
    w, err := archive.CreateHeader(&zip.FileHeader{
        Name:     "someZipFile/" + filenames[i],
        Method:   zip.Deflate,
        Modified: time.Now(),
    })
```

Change the call to create the archive file as shown here.  Use the other code in the question as is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @eagergopher's reply, I was able to build a proper solution

Here's  the result

```
archive := zip.NewWriter(w)
            attachment := "attachment; filename=someZipFile.zip")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", attachment)

            for i := 0; i < len(bodies); i++ { // bodies are response bodies,corresponding to "downloaded" files
                defer bodies[i].Close()
                fmt.Println(filenames[i])}

                w, err := archive.CreateHeader(&zip.FileHeader{
                Name:     filenames[i],
                Method:   zip.Deflate,
                Modified: time.Now(),
                })

                if err != nil {
                  fmt.Println("Header couldn't be created")
                  return true
                }

                if _, err := io.Copy(w, bodies[i]); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("File couldn't be written")
                    return true
                }

            }
            archive.Close()
            return false
})
```